# Xcode build fail on m1 chip

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a flutter app in Xcode on my Mac (m1 chip). But it fails due to below error.

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

As the warning says, my guess is that the issue occur while it trying to build it for arm64. But I have already add aram64 in excluded arch list.

I'm running Xcode on rosetta & also its build successfully on iOS 12 & iOS 14 simulators but the issue comes when I try to build it on real device with iOS 14.3 and also in archive build. What I'm doing wrong here?

[image: Error message]

[image: My changes in arch section]

Answer (score 0):

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The error you've encountered could be due to many reasons. It would be better if you can isolate the issue by performing the workaround that was discussed in [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75167#issuecomment-850675377).

> Sent here from:
> [#76302](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76302)
>
> So I was having this issue after trying every flutter clean / podfile
> delete sequence under the sun. Turns out my flutter got stuck at an
> old version that is evidently not compatible with the latest version
> of xcode or something (who really knows).
>
> So I had to run
>
> - `flutter upgrade --force`
> - `flutter clean`
> - delete Podfile and Podfile.lock
> - run `pub get`
> - re-run my build_runner stuff (you may not have this)
> - `flutter run` (to run the app on device with all this new stuff / regenerate podfile stuff)
>
> Then I was finally able to get my ios archive to build with `flutter build ipa`.
>
> FYI: The flutter upgrade command pushed me from `2.0.5` -> `2.2.1` on
> the stable channel. Prior to this, I was just getting generic warnings
> of `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`.